# Image not loading on html file in android mobile

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to view my HTML file on the android mobile browser.
My HTML file has the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testy</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Captain is Here</h1>
    <img src='captain.jpg' width='30%' alt='Testy'/>
</body>

</html>
```

The image(captain.jpg) is also in the same folder where the HTML page is located. I'm getting the image on the computer browser but when I'm trying to open it in mobile browser image, not showing. I tried giving different file paths. How can I achieve this by giving a universal path by that a mobile that containing these HTML files should open in respective browsers and render images too?

Comment: Are you opening this script locally on phone? Are you sure the images is already included on your phone?

Comment: Yes sure. I copied a folder that contains an image and HTML file to both internal and external storage. But it didn't work.

Comment: So can you try changing the URL from `whatever.htm` to `captain.png` and see what's happening?

Comment: try give prefix `./` so it becomes `./captain.png`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman It's not worked like that I tried.

Comment: @FahmiJabbar I tried in that way too. It's not worked. I tried by giving an absolute path for image location on mobile but that one also not worked

Comment: I'm assuming you are opening html file on your android browser. If you can open the html file, there must be an URL you can use e.g `file://...`, then try to change the URL like @PraveenKumarPurushothaman said. If the images show, then use that URL.

Comment: Yea, @FahmiJabbar looks like the image is not read by the phone.

Comment: I `file:///sdcard/Testy/captain.png` as it's not working But I checked by giving `file:///sdcard` as it gave my files list. But when I opening HTML file on browser the URL is `content://com.coloros.filemanager/external_dir/Testy/testy.html` my mobile is Realme so its having **coloros**

Comment: what happen if you try to open the images by `content://com.coloros.filemanager/external_dir/Testy/captain.png`? Last solution I wanted to give to you is just host it on github pages. Since it's just a static html.

Comment: Yeah, if you try any web URLs it's working but I just want to know the reason why local files are not working.

Answer (score 0):

1- your image size is too large try an image with a smaller size or resize or format your image into a smaller size.

try `src-'./caption.jpg'` instead of `src='caption.jpg'`

Comment: It's not worked for me. I tried giving `file:///sdcard/Testy/captain.jpg` but it's not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Opening through directry location of Html in Chrome Solve this.

For that get html file location directry in details by file manager
Example `storage/emulated/0/web_folder/file.html` and copy it

After that
1.Open chrome
2.type `file:///` and Paste directry location
3.`"file:///storage/emulated/0/web_folder/file.html"` Now it can run with image

Ensure that storage permission allowed to chrome
For that Open permission settings for chrome and allow storage permission

Comment: Not possible in every android mobile due to different file URLs being maintained by different vendors. like content://, file://

Comment: Get the directry Location by filemanger in details i said that url for only example purpose

Comment: Even I gave location according to my filemanger I couldn't load image in my HTML page

Answer (score 0):

### that's where `mhtml` and URLs get used!!!

> Have you ever downloaded a page using chrome in android? if so you would have known about mhtml

> MHTML, an initialism of "MIME encapsulation of aggregate HTML documents", is a *web page archive format* used to combine, in a single computer file, the HTML code and its companion resources (*such as images*, Flash animations, Java applets, and audio and video files) that are ***represented by external hyperlinks*** in the web page's HTML code

> to convert your html to mhtml you may use some *tools* but you can also do it **manually** .

> converting need ***not*** rename the file as `index.mhtml` but use all necessary files as hyperlinks

> you may use image hosting sites like [imgur](https://imgur.com/) *or* [imgbb](https://imgbb.com/) *or* even firebase if your familiar.
>
> after you host get the link by

1. right-clicking image
2. open **image** in new tab
3. copy link
4. use it(link) instead of captain.jpg

### [Here is an example of how to get link using imgbb](https://s10.gifyu.com/images/output-onlinegiftools2cbb605f2c3d3cb1.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting you pretty simple steps to solve this issue.

Images will be loaded if file path is correct.

- Download the image associated to HTML page in your phone via chrome.
- Open the same in phones's browser and you will see the workable file path in URL section.
- Copy that path.
- Insert the copied path in HTML file.
- Done